# AJAX post to php request issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I'm wanting to post a variable from ajax js file to a php file. here is my attempt so far.

```
       var request = createRequest();
      var deletenode = node.id;
   window.alert("nodeid=" + deletenode);
       var vars = "deletenode="+deletenode;
       request.open("POST", "deletenode.php", true);
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    handleRequest(request);
};
       request.send("deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(deletenode));
```

here is my php file

```
 <?php
 print_r($_POST);
 $node = $_POST['deletenode'];
 print "node to be deleted: $node";
 ?>
```

nothing comes up in my php file, what can be the issue. my ajax request is intact and working right too. thank you and here is my handle request.

```
function handleRequest(request) {
    // we only care for now about when we get to readyState 4
    // which means the request completed and we have the response back
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        //alert("response: " + request.responseText); // check to see what
        // we got back just for testing
        // now get response's TEXT and put into document (specify where)
        // below we have an html element with the id as timeLoc
        json= eval ("(" + request.responseText + ")");;

        //alert ("json="+json); //tests what was recieved
        //clicking the close button
        closeButton.onclick = function() {
            node.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
            node.eachAdjacency(function(adj) {
                adj.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
                var request = createRequest();
                var deletenode = node.id;
                window.alert("nodeid=" + deletenode);
                var vars = "deletenode="+deletenode;
                request.open("POST", "deletenode.php", true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    handleRequest(request);
                };
                request.send("deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(deletenode));
            });       
        }// end readystate=4
    }//end handle request
```

Comment: I highly recommend you use a Javascript framework like jQuery. It makes cross-browser compatibility issues so much easier.

Comment: check your browser console and see what data is sent abd what is the response from server

Comment: After formatting your code its easy to see it is not written properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you have to send the data as key/value pairs - `request.send("deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(deletenode));`

Comment: I edited already to what you suggested as seen above but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @user1902588 Show your `handleRequest` function.

Comment: all this code is nested in the request, so Im wanting to do a request in a request.

Comment: @user1902588 okay but still show the whole `handleRequest` function

Comment: @user1902588 do not reuse the request object use a new one for each request you make.

Comment: I made a new object and it still doesnt send anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a copy/paste error, but if that's your actual code you appear to be missing a few curly braces closes. And have a double;; at the end of your eval line. This is the code tidied up with the extra curly braces, does that work?

```
 function handleRequest(request) {
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        json= eval ("(" + request.responseText + ")");
        closeButton.onclick = function() {
            node.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
            node.eachAdjacency(function(adj) {
                adj.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
                var request = createRequest();
                var deletenode = node.id;
                window.alert("nodeid=" + deletenode);
                var vars = "deletenode="+deletenode;
                request.open("POST", "deletenode.php", true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    handleRequest(request);
                };
                request.send("deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(deletenode));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, @Musa, you tidied up as I did!

Comment: yeah, It was a copy paste error. Everything is syntax correct

Comment: If you open Chrome Dev Tools and go to the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network), you should be able to see this request being made, and explore the data being sent, does it look right there?